# Vertical CSS slide menu pushing the site up on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

The submenu on each menu item slides underneath the main menu item instead of sliding out whenever I click on a menu item, which is what it's supposed to do.  Problem is the site itself automatically scrolls up.  Its as if the main menu items have a link to them that is anchored to the top of the site.  I click on them, the submenu slide out, but the site itself scrolls up everytime.

How to make the code cross-browser compatible?

The javascript code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
 startList = function() {

 if (document.getElementById) {
navRoot = document.getElementById("nav");
for (i=0; i<navRoot.childNodes.length; i++) {
    node = navRoot.childNodes[i];
    if (node.nodeName=="LI") {
    node.onclick=function() {

 this.className = (this.className == "on") ? "off" : "on";

        }
    }
}
  }
 }
 window.onload=startList;
 //--><!]]>
 </script>
```

The html code:

```
 <ul id="nav">
 <li><a href="#">Home </a></li>
 <li><a href="#">About &gt;</a> 
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">History </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Team </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Offices </a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Services &gt;</a> 
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Web Design </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Internet Marketing </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Hosting </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Domain Names </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Broadband </a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us &gt;</a> 
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">United Kingdom</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">France</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">USA</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Australia</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Based off of this menu: http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/drop-down-expand.htm#

Comment: please make a jsFiddle file so that we can edit your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you have "#" in your hrefs...this is telling the browser to return to the top. You need to return false on your onclick so that the default behavior (navigating to the href) doesn't happen on the items that are not truly "links".

Comment: Thanks for the direct answer! At the moment, it has solved my problem.  I feel like an idiot for not noticing the # in the hrefs..

Comment: No worries man.  It happens to the best of us.  That kind of menu for me is usually quicker to implement and easier to accomplish using jQuery. If you were using it, you could do what Derek recommended in his answer...although that isn't going to help you much if you just want to keep it plain JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can always add `e.preventDefault()` to the event listener to remove all hyperlink-effects after clicked.

Using `preventDefault` is usually more recommended.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z8Uvj/

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    //your stuff
    e.preventDefault();
});
```